# Cucumber deprecated Main class

Tags: selenium, automation, cucumber, cucumber-java

I'm new to cucumber and couldn't find any solution for this error

```
cucumber.api.cli.Main run

WARNING: You are using deprecated Main class. Please use io.cucumber.core.cli.Main
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/tagexpressions/TagExpressionParser
at io.cucumber.core.options.CucumberPropertiesParser.parse(CucumberPropertiesParser.java:83)
at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.run(Main.java:48)
at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:30)
at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/tagexpressions/TagExpressionParser
... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.cucumber.tagexpressions.TagExpressionParser
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)`enter code here`
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 4 more
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow, find information on how to ask a good question here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Please give some context what you were trying to achieve when this error popped up. Also, you can format your code with the code editor - feel free to edit you question accordingly.

Comment: I am using Cucumber framework for Selenium and when compiling feature file this error is generating.
Feature: To test the Login Functionality


  Scenario: Check Login is successful with valid credentials

    Given User is on Login Page

    When User enters username and password

    And Clicks on login button

    Then User is navigated to Homepage

Comment: Use io.cucumber.core.cli.Main . You need to use latest version of cucumber refer https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton/blob/main/pom.xml for pom file